# ¿Cómo recuperar un objeto de una Lista de objetos mediante stream?

Tags: java, stream

estoy intentando recuperar un objeto(Usuario) utilizando stream y no lo consigo.
Cada usuario tiene un código único, y lo que quiero es recuperar el usuario con el código "tal".

Si casteo, cuando ejecuto la App, me da una classCastException.

```
public Usuario findUser(List<?extends Usuario> usuarios, String codigo)
{
  return (Usuario)usuarios.stream()
 .filter(usuario -> usuario.getCodigo().equals(codigo));
}
```

Imagino que no habrá que castear y que me faltara codigo, 
muchas gracias de antemano por la ayudita.

EDITADO:

esta es lo que he hecho y me ha funcionado:

```
public Alumno findAlumno(List<Alumno> alumnitos, String codigo) {

  return alumnitos.stream()
        .filter(alumno -> alumno.getCodigo().equals(codigo))
        .findFirst().orElse(null);      
}
```

Abajo un compañero tiene una solución que también funciona y es muy muy parecida a esta, casi la misma, hay sutiles diferencias.
Pero quiero dejar constancia de lo que yo he hecho y me ha funcionado por si a alguien le interesa.

Considero que su solución no es la misma que la mía, porque, entre otras cosas, el usa un "optional" y hace un "casteo", a mi no me ha hecho falta

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando *transformas* una lista a un stream, necesitas hacer el paso opuesto después:

```
public Usuario findUser(List<?extends Usuario> usuarios, String codigo) {
    return usuarios.stream()
       .filter(usuario -> usuario.getCodigo().equals(codigo))
       .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
}
```

Pero ya que estás seguro de que sólo hay un elemento, podrías hacer:

```
public Usuario findUser(List<?extends Usuario> usuarios, String codigo) {
    Optional<Usuario> temp= usuarios.stream()
       .findAny(usuario -> usuario.getCodigo().equals(codigo));

    return temp.orElse(null); //si el opcional está vacío devuelve null
}
```

Comment: hola, muchas gracias, antes en el curro lo he conseguido, pero no me hace falta lo del optional, no se como lo he hecho, es decir si he usado el findAny pero no se como lo he hecho y me ha funcionado.